# "No Python at..." error after installing different version and changing the path variable

Tags: python, path-variables

I use Windows 10. I was trying to pip install Vectorbt but the installation could not have been finished because there was an error when numba and llvmlite were suppose to be installed. I was using Python 3.10 and read that there is a compatibility problem with it. So I uninstalled it and installed Python 3.8.7. Afterwards I made sure that the system variable is set on the proper Python path. I closed everything and even restarted the system but in the command line or the powershell terminal in VSC I get the error "No Python at" and the directory of the previous 3.10 installation.
The variable is set corectly (was set as an admin).

Any ideas?

Maybe something with the registry?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check if VS Code somehow retained a wrong interpreter path? You can press `Ctrl+Shift+P` and type 'interpreter' then select 'Python > Select Interpreter' from the drop down. Do you get the same error if you open cmd/powershell outside of VS Code?

Comment: Are you using virtual environments? Can you create steps to reproduce the problem, starting from a new computer that doesn't have Python installed?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you use virtual environments to manage python versions (you'll never look back), high level steps:

1. cd mydir
2. virtualenv .venv # creates a virtual env dev (or `python3 -m venv .venv`)
3. source .venv/bin/activate # activates the virtual env
4. pip install -r requirements.txt # installs the required dependencies
5. python -m pytest # runs the unit tests

More details in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html